How to make 2nd div to overlay 1st background div in 2 div system with accurate scroll bar height
There are 2 divs. 1st div is full page and is 'fixed', not scrollable. I want to make the 2nd div to be scrollable, just like there is 1 div that takes the whole viewport.
The y scroll bar shows up, and you can scroll, but it does not work 100%.
The problem:

Y Scroll bar is from div.outer-container, its height is correct when loaded as it's based on 2 div children height. But, when scrolling begins, the height will not be correct, due to 1st child div is fixed.

Behavior:


2.1) Drag scroll bar to bottom, "Bottom" test does not show up, as the scroll bar height is not short enough to show it.

2.2) If using mouse scroll wheel, it will scroll to bottom, just like screenshot above. The y scroll bar shows that you already scrolled to the bottom. But, if you click the 2nd div, and continue to use the wheel to scroll, you are able to see the bottom of the 2nd div "Bottom".


I think the scroll bar height for 2nd div is not correct, due to 1 child is 'fixed' and not scrollable.

What I want to achieve:

Scroll 2nd div like there is just 1 div. Treat 1st div as background.
I need 1st div, which will contain more complex components. There is not such assumption that 1st div is just a background image.
I think CSS scroll bar will not work, and it has to use JS to dynamically to handle this.
2nd div could contain any component in the future.

How to make the y scroll to work perfectly in above configuration?
    === TwoDiv.jsx ===

    import React from 'react';
    import './TwoDiv.css';

    const TwoDiv = () => {
      return (
        <div className="outer-container">
          <div className="background-section">
            <h1>Full Screen Background</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="content-section">
            <h1>Top</h1>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <p>Row</p>
            <h1>Bottom</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default TwoDiv;

    === TwoDiv.css ===

    .outer-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200vh;
      overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
    }

    .background-section {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh; 
      background-color: lightblue; 
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .content-section {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 2;
      margin-top: 100vh;
      background-color: white; 
    }


Correct me if I understood your question wrong, you want to create a page, where fixed div will be displayed as a hero container and will always be available on the background and the next divs should behave like this is a default page.
So, to meet your goal we should focus on css only, since there is no problems in your jsx component.
The page have 2 y-scrollbars:

the first one is a scrollbar of the whole page;
the second scrollbar is related to your content section, because it does not fit into parent container size.

To fix the issue with double scrollbar I recommend to remove fixed height and overflow-y from .outer-container class.
.outer-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

Let me know if you need any help or if I understood your question in wrong way.

Remove these does make it work perfectly:     height: 200vh;
overflow-y: auto; With it, scroll is weird. thanks.
